# Two arrays cloned with Lodash, separate but the same. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I know for a fact there is something pretty obvious here that I am completely missing, so your help is greatly appreciated.

I have a feature that provides two dropdowns. They contain the same data (the feature allows a trade between two people, the people is the data), but I want them each to get their own copy of said data.

Another part of this feature is that by picking Person A in the first dropdown, I want to disable Person A in the second dropdown, and vice versa, so I have the `ng-options` tag paying attention to a `disabled` property on the object.

The issue I have is that even with using a method such as Lodash's `clone` to properly create a "new" array upon first time assignment, every time I access Person A in ONE array (and specifically do NOT access the other array) invariably I am seeing that when I touch Person A, that object is updated in BOTH arrays, which has me flustered.

This feels like a down-to-the-metal, barebones Javascript issue (standard PEBCAK, I feel like I'm clearly misunderstanding or straight up missing something fundamental), maybe with a bit of AngularJS rendering-related fun-ness involved, but... What gives?

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('weirdDataController', function($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('manager1_id', () => {
      if (angular.isDefined($scope.manager1_id) && parseInt($scope.manager1_id, 10) > 0) {
        $scope._disableManagerInOtherDropdown(false, $scope.manager1_id);
      }
    });

    $scope.$watch('manager2_id', () => {
      if (angular.isDefined($scope.manager2_id) && parseInt($scope.manager2_id, 10) > 0) {
        $scope._disableManagerInOtherDropdown(true, $scope.manager2_id);
      }
    });

    $scope._gimmeFakeData = () => {
      return [{
          manager_id: 1,
          manager_name: 'Bill',
          disabled: false
        },
        {
          manager_id: 2,
          manager_name: 'Bob',
          disabled: false
        },
        {
          manager_id: 3,
          manager_name: 'Beano',
          disabled: false
        },
        {
          manager_id: 4,
          manager_name: 'Barf',
          disabled: false
        },
        {
          manager_id: 5,
          manager_name: 'Biff',
          disabled: false
        },
      ];
    };

    const data = $scope._gimmeFakeData();
    $scope.firstManagers = _.clone(data);
    $scope.secondManagers = _.clone(data);

    $scope._disableManagerInOtherDropdown = (otherIsFirstArray, managerId) => {
      const disableManagers = manager => {
        manager.disabled = manager.manager_id === managerId;
      };

      if (otherIsFirstArray) {
        $scope.firstManagers.forEach(disableManagers);
      } else {
        $scope.secondManagers.forEach(disableManagers);
      }

      console.log('Is the first item the same??', $scope.firstManagers[0].disabled === $scope.secondManagers[0].disabled);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="weirdDataController">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="manager1_id" ng-options="manager.manager_id as manager.manager_name disable when manager.disabled for manager in firstManagers track by manager.manager_id">
      <option value="" disabled="disabled">Choose one manager</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="manager2_id" ng-options="manager.manager_id as manager.manager_name disable when manager.disabled for manager in secondManagers track by manager.manager_id">
      <option value="" disabled="disabled">Choose another manager</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
```

I threw everything relevant on `$scope` just for the sake of getting it working and illustrating the issue, but here's how it goes:

- On init, I grab the array, then clone a copy for each dropdown
- When each dropdown changes the model property (the object ID), I have a scope listener then call a method to handle disabling the selected object/person in the OPPOSITE list
- Within this method, I determine which of the two lists/arrays to iterate through and mark the disabled object
- At the end of this method, I do a simple console.log call to check the value of a given object. For quick-and-dirty simplicity, I just grab item at index 0 .
- What I expected: one object have a `disabled` value of `true`, and the opposite object to have `false`. What I see: they both have `true` (assuming you select the first "real" item in the dropdown)

What's the deal? How big of an idiot am I being?

Comment: You've copied the arrays but they both reference the same object instances. So mutating objects in one array will cause the same mutations in the other array since they're references to the same objects.

Comment: Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how `clone` works? When I first started the feature, I was indeed just doing simple assignment, and so it was a shared array, but then I started using `clone` to remedy that. Let me go read the docs again and see.

Comment: Yes, you want [`_.cloneDeep()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep).

Comment: Actually, if you look at the example they provide for [`_.clone()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#clone), they're demonstrating the exact behavior you seem to be confused about.

Comment: That's the part that I derped hard on. I was aware of deep cloning, but thought that it was one layer beneath where I was, and just assumed that arrays with "simple" objects would be OK? I dunno why I did, but that's where I was. I've learned this one the hard way. Go ahead and provide an answer and I'll mark it correct, you sir are the winner :)

Comment: Just as an aside, I think Patrick hit the nail on the head here, in that while cloneDeep solves the problem, the problem ends up being a bit of a code smell in how the feature was laid out. I backed up and re-thought about how the feature was designed (by myself, 4 years ago?) and updated it accordingly to better handle a separation between the UI and the underlying data. I appreciate all of the help!

Comment: Yeah I started writing an answer along those lines and realized it would have taken more work than I initially thought. I didn't want to leave you with a subpar solution or a half-baked idea about a better approach so I opted to just leave it. I'm glad you were able to figure it out yourself though.

Comment: @Mattygabe, it would be useful if you would post an answer yourself, so that this question ... well, has an answer ;-) It is quite OK to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question was: `clone()` does not perform a "deep" clone by default, therefore I was dealing with the same array despite making the flawed attempt that I was not. Using Lodash's `cloneDeep()` method solved my issue, but as Patrick suggested I reevaluated how I wrote the method in question and refactored it, which I removed the need to use any cloning at all.